# No system images installed android after installing adt bundle?

Tags: android, api

I have few questions regarding ADT Bundle(revision 23.0.2).
After downloading I get android sdk tools and android4.4W (wear). Can I develop apps using this sdk for smartphones?
Another is when I create AVD it shows that there is no system images installed for devices I selected. It shows images only for android wear. Please help me that can i develope app with this API 20 for smartphones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 4.4W is Android Wear and is NOT an sdk for smartphones, it is an API target for wearables. So NO you cannot use this SDK to develop apps for smartphones.You need to use the SDK Manager to download the system images for this particular SDK platform.

In order to develop a wearable app, you will have to create a separate project and bundle it with your main .apk file unless using Android Studio which will allow you to create both in a single setup wizard. Android studio makes it much simpler than eclipse to create an app that will bundle your wearable app when your normal app is installed.

please see : http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html

Comment: No problem. I would really suggest using Android Studio and following the guide linked above. It is very useful. see this http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html